# SASS random() always returns same value, why?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

As you can see here: http://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/alkmL
I'm trying to convert some javascript functions into SASS. Everything works fine but this one function...

I want to convert this:

```
var pallete = Math.floor(Math.random() * 210);

$("article h2").each(function(i) {
  var hue = pallete + (i * 15);
  var css = 'background:hsl(' + hue + ',85%,70%); color:hsl(' + hue + ',45%,55%);';
  $(this).attr("style", css);
});
```

Into something like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through $articles {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    $random: random(210);
    $hue: $random + ($i * 15);
    background-color: hsl($hue, 85%, 70%);
    color: hsl($hue, 45%, 55%);
  }
}
```

My problem in this case is, that `random(210)` always returns the same value on each page load. Is it possible to get different values from random on each run through `@for`?

Comment: Be aware that `random()` is not currently a function of Sass or Compass, it is something specific to CodePen (see:  https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1154 and https://github.com/nex3/sass/pull/904)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible in any proper production setup. Browsers only understand CSS so SASS and pretty much all other CSS preprocessors usually run once (on the server), not on the client for each page load.

While for example LESS has a client-side compiler (less.js), using it slows down the page loading process and is usually only suitable for development. If you really want dynamic colors, consider building the relevant CSS using JavaScript or keeping the old code.

Comment: Not true. You can compile SASS, LESS etc on client side. Which is of course bad idea, but still possible.

Comment: @dragoste Note the word **usually**

Comment: @Pinocchio Note ThiefMaster's expression "that's not possible."

Comment: Answer updated. I know less has a client-side compiler but i hope nobody uses that for a production site.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: the shocking thing is just how many people *do* use it in production. :-(

Comment: Well I solved it. As you can see here: http://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/alkmL So now it is full CSS.